# Cron Jobs Parse error

Tags: php, laravel, cron, cpanel, laravel-5.1

I`m working on laravel 5.1 application  and i need to use **Laravel Task Schedule** it's working well in my local server.

But when i use cron job on my web hosting server i face this error

`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CLASS, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or '$' in /home/titglobal/public_html/ElAQSA/artisan on line 31`

This is my Cron Command in my server

`/usr/local/bin/php /home/titglobal/public_html/ElAQSA/artisan schedule:run > /home/titglobal/cron.log 2>&1`

**Note:**  Also i tried to use 
`* * * * * php /path/to/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1`

as laravel Doc mentioned the same error in html page

**my app use PHP 5.6  but the default php version in web hosting server  php v 5.3**

Comment: that's not a cron problem. that's your php script blowing up. you're probably using a feature of PHP 5.6 that ISN'T in 5.3, and there's nothing you can do to fix it, other than by NOT using that new language feature, or upgrading your server's PHP to a version that DOES support that feature.

Comment: `/home/titglobal/public_html/` – Interesting project name(?). You’ll probably need to use another PHP executable than the one under `/usr/local/bin/php`

Comment: @MarcB: your diagnosis is spot on, but "not using that language feature" is not an option in this case, because the framework being used requires PHP 5.5+ by itself.

Comment: Get your dev environment and your server environment running same versions.

Comment: i know laravel 5.1 requires php v 5.5.9+ , but i can run it via cpanel  -> select php version  to set my app to proper version to run 
i think now my app use php 5.5.9 features  so i can use Laravel Task Schedule . Am A right ? @MarcB

Comment: Well, what's on line 31 of this script? Because we can't help you without knowing what the actual code at/around that spot is. The cront itself is useless, since that by itself is perfectly fine. This is a purely PHP issue, and has nothing to do with cron.

Comment: @JustUser: the setting in cPanel only affects the PHP you get when your scripts run in the browser, not the PHP you get in the command line. You need to contact the hosting provider and ask them about this - it's obvious that your `/usr/local/bin/php` binary invokes PHP 5.3, you need to invoke some different binary to get PHP 5.6 on the command line (I'm guessing `/usr/local/bin/php56` might be the right answer.)

Comment: @MarcB: [this is line 31 in question](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/v5.1.0/artisan#L31). It's not OP's own code, it's part of the Laravel framework. Modifying that line will just move the error to the next place where the framework uses modern features.

Comment: @DCoder:Firstly thanks to refer to artisan file as a part of laravel framwork, and i have been changed  `/usr/local/bin/php` To `/usr/local/bin/php56`   but  my cron.log  change to `/usr/local/cpanel/bin/jailshell: /usr/local/bin/php56: No such file or directory`

Comment: @JustUser: then, as I said earlier, you need to contact the hosting provider and ask. They know their environment, we don't.

Comment: @DCoder: the hosting provider he that give me `/usr/local/bin/php`
instead of `php`

Comment: @JustUser: evidently that's not the right answer, or your script would work correctly. Create a PHP file that contains only this: `<?php echo "PHP version is ", PHP_VERSION;`, and set up a cron task to run it. Check the log output to see which version of PHP it reports. If it reports 5.3, show that to your hosting provider.

Comment: @DCoder: thank you for help :)

Comment: @DCoder:I did it after that the hosting provider gave me the correct path  for php 5.5  `/usr/local/php55/bin/php` now it`s working thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to see the php_info and look at where you active php ini is (path).
Then you get an idea where you php executable is.

Finally you can use it to compile your cron files.

You could use SSH too.

Comment: thanks @yassine for help but the issue was with **php path** no more